# Brother MFC-290C printer for Ubuntu

Tags: drivers, printing

Can someone instruct me how to install the **Brother MFC-290C** printer driver for Ubuntu?

Thank you.

Comment: Use the CUPS (Common Unix Printing System) administrative interface at `http://;pcalhost:631/admin`

Comment: @waltinator That link is coming up as invalid for me. Is there a typo in it?

Comment: `http://localhost:631/admin` is the un-typoed version

Comment: +1 for an awesome local host webpage. I see this about once a year and forget about it shortly after. If you ever write a self-answered question on local hosts webpages (including this one) let me know and I'll gladly upvote the Q and the A :)

Comment: **Close voters** - It appears to be the consensus of the reviewers who close voted this question that it is "unclear what you're asking" however it is clearly not "unclear what you're asking".

Answer (score 0):

Go to this [link](http://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadtop.aspx?c=us&lang=en&prod=mfc290c_all):

[image: brother mfc-290c]

- First option check on `Linux`
- Second option check on `Linux (deb)`
- Then click the <kbd>Search</kbd> button

The next screen provides many files you can download but selecting the first tool only: `Driver Install Tool` should select the appropriate ones needed and install them.

Answer (score 0):

that is a very helpful post above; I think the installer tool comes down as a compressed file and is usually run from the terminal;

so if one opens a terminal; copy each line below 1 by 1; paste into the terminal; hit the ENTER key; move to the next line

```
cd Downloads

gunzip linux-brprinter-installer-2.2.0-1.gz

sudo bash linux-brprinter-installer-2.2.0-1 MFC-290C
```

and watch the installer as it runs, as it will ask questions of you